# A href catching

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup for parsing some html. Here is the content:

```
<tr> 
<th>Your provider:</th> 
<td> 

<img src="/isp_logos/la-la-la.ico" alt=""/> 
 <a href="/isp/SomeProvider"> 
 Provider name </a> 
 &nbsp;
 <a href="http://*/isp-comparer/?isp=000000"> 
 </a> 
</td> 
</tr>
```

I have to get **SomeProvider** text from the link . My code is:

```
contentSoup = BeautifulSoup(ThatHtml)
print contentSoup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('/isp/(.*)'))
```

The result is empty array, why? Maybe there are another ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your posted code and input, I'm getting:

```
[<a href="/isp/SomeProvider">   Provider name </a>]
```

As the return of the array. Are you using the newest 3.1.x version of BeautifulSoup? I actually had the same problem, but it turns out I downloaded the 2.x version of BeautifulSoup thinking that the 2.x meant it was compatible with python 2.x.

Assuming that the first  contains the SomeProvider, you could just use:

```
contentSoup.a
```

to extract that tag.